# Can I use the likelihood to estimate probability of draws

Tags: probability, bayesian, estimation, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

I need to estimate $P(data)$ for a Bayesian problem, supposing I have the distribution on which the data are being drawn, can I use the likelihood to estimate that?

I'm asking because as far as I know, likelihood is not a probability, but for discrete rv it's like considering
$$
P(X_1=x_1 \cap X_2=x_2 \cap ... \cap X_n=x_n) \; \;X_i \:iid
$$

But we can't do this for abs. continuous rv right? So in addition to the previous one, how can we estimate $P(data)$ for abs. cont. rv?

I'm referring to:
$$
P(hyp|data) = \frac{P(data|hyp) * P(hyp)}{P(data)}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n$ are i.i.d., then by the definition of independence

$$
p(X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(X_i)
$$

As for $P(data)$, it is

$$
P(data) = \int P(data|hyp) * P(hyp) \; d \,hyp
$$

by the law of total probability.

Comment: The convolution in the integral must be replaced by multiplication (`\cdot` in LaTeX).

Comment: @cdalitz it's not convolution, I used the same notation as OP for multiplication.

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer, but with this formula, how do I find the probability of an hypothesis... also, with that integral, you mean to find it on [-inf, +inf]?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia $P(hyp)$ in Bayes theorem is something you either know or assume  (prior). The integral is over the support of the distribution.

Comment: You can estimate $p(hyp)$ (note that it is a density, not a probability in this formula) non-prametrically with a kernel density estimator. You won't need to numerically integrate over $(-\infty,\infty)$, because your data will have a finite $hyp_{min}$ and $hyp_{max}$.